# XSensors is giving me scary readings ?

Tags: cooling, intel-core2, heatsink, lm-sensors

I am these readings from XSensors, really scary can someone tell me what might be wrong with my system. I did replace the thermal compound with Cooler Master HTK-002 still no difference the temperature reached a staggering 97 degrees while watching youtube.

I am using C2D E4500 , DG41RQ mobo and a 400 W PSU with no discrete graphics card.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Cheers,

Utsav

Comment: You have 5 fans but only 1 is running?

Comment: No, I have only 1 fan.

Comment: What is the question exactly?
Is this a laptop? These usually run quite hot, nothing to be worried about as long as you stay below 100ºC... worst case the CPU is going to throttle itself to keep from burning. 57 looks pretty good to me.